# Cannot backup WhatsApp to Google account on Family Link

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive, google-family-link

I have Family Link control over my daughter. Now, we bought her a new Android phone. The phone is under her own account we created on Google. Now, we have installed WhatsApp. But when we go to backup options in WhatsApp trying to backup the WhatsApp data to her Google account, WhatsApp comments that this cannot be done. I suspect it is due to the Family Link.

After approving all apps for her with zero limitations, I still cannot back up WhatsApp data to her Google account.

How to solve such an issue?

Comment: Could you add to this post the **error's screenshot**?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp backs the data up to a Google Drive account and I don't think Family Link accounts for under-13 accounts allow Google Drive. So, that might be why WhatsApp fails to back up the chat history.

Answer (score 0):

I also found not possible to restore a WhatsApp backup from a gmail account under Family Link control

This is how I resolved:

- Removed the  Family Link controlled gmail account from the older phone
- Added another temporary gmail account to the older phone
- Backup WhatsApp from the older phone to the temporary gmail account
- Added the temporary gmail account to the new phone
- Installed Whatsapp and restored the Backup on the new phone
- Removed the temporary gmail account
- Added my daughter gmail account to the new phone